# Making a logo file print ready for embossing without having spoken to the printer

Tags: print-design, logo

I don't believe this has already been asked on Stack Exchange.

I'm finishing up a project to design a logo for a client who was originally planning to have his logo embossed/stamped onto stainless steel tumblers (vacuum flasks).

He has informed me, recently, that he isn't sure anymore, whether he is going to emboss the logo or just have it printed on the tumblers.

I told him I should speak with his printer to find out any specific information needed to properly prepare the logo file for embossing. I told him this before he mentioned that he was no longer certain about whether he would be embossing or printing the logo. When he told me that, he said not to worry about preparing the file for print, one way or another because he has enough knowledge of Illustrator to go in and make any changes that may be specified by his printer, once he's made the final decision to emboss or not to emboss.

I accept what he's told me (for the most part), since it is his logo, after all, but what I'm wondering is whether there are certain basic preparations I could make without having spoken to the printer that would be helpful to my client so as to avoid any complications with the final product, once he's made up his mind on what he wants to do and has to go in and modify his file to printer specification.

Are there some general things (besides the design being in vector, cmyk, font in outlines, etc.) with respect to the spacing between elements or die lines or anything that I could make sure to have in place?

The logo itself is not overly complex. It uses thick, rounded fonts, is all in one color(black), and there are no intricate paths or visual effects present, either. Hopefully, those things alone will be enough to promote a hassle free printing experience, whether or not the decision to emboss is made.

Maybe, I could give him two vector files for the logo, one that is as emboss ready as possible and another, as optimal as possible for non-embossing print job.

I have never designed a logo that was to be embossed on to a metal surface before. I work with developers so they can't help.

If anyone who has some experience with the process of embossing on to stainless steel or has designed a logo that was embossed could give some advice, I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: Your client already told you he can edit the Illustrator, so why worry about it? It seems you answered your own question. Just send a logo that is ready to print (no embedded text, shapes merged when possible, no transparency issues, etc).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I tend to make things more difficult than need be...and the logo is good to go as far as merged elements, text, color, and transparency, also.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is probably fine. Just note whoever does the print or embossing, they may actually need a black only logo version. Even if they make the print in yellow for instance, presumably in a RAL color, they might still need a black only logo version. So make everything 100% black with outlined text and you're probably done.

Send a package of the black only & cmyk versions so you're 100% sure they have all the info, with these sent, there's not much else they can request from you, as most printers can normally also make their own adjustments inhouse if needed.

Comment: Well, unless he decides to alter the color on his own, I believe my client only needs it in all black for the moment and that's how it is - 100% black - in Illustrator already so that won't be an issue.